Express the Chi and uniform distributions as the limit of some coin tossing
The exponential distribution is the continuous limit of the geometric.
What would be the coin-toss equivalent of the Chi and the uniform distributions in the following sense?
For a sequence $p_{1..\infty} = (p_1, p_2, ...)$ define $X_{1..\infty}$ as the integer random variable
$$
X_{1..\infty} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\begin{cases}0 &\text{ with probability }p_1 \\ 1+X_{2..\infty} &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
In other words, you toss coins with success probabilities $p_i$, stopping on the first success and counting failures.
Now let $X$ be a Chi distribution (question 1) or a uniform distribution in $[0,1]$ (question 2).
What kind of sequence $p_1, p_2, ...$ ($p_i$ as a function of $n$) is such that for all $a\geq 0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left(\frac{X_{p_{1..\infty}}}{n} > a\right) = \Pr(X>a) \quad?
$$

We solve the problem assuming we can allow $p_i\in [0,1]$. If we want to require that $p_i\in (0,1)$, all we need to do is perturb $p_i$ by a little if it equals $0$ or $1$.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $$p_i(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{n+1-i} & : 1\leqslant i\leqslant n \\ 0 & : n<i.\end{array}\right.$$ We note that for $0\leqslant k<n$, \begin{align*} p_{k+1}\prod_{i=1}^k (1-p_i) & = \frac{1}{n+1-(k+1)}\prod_{i=1}^k\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n+1-i} \Bigr) \\ & = \frac{1}{n+1-(k+1)}\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{n-i}{n+1-i} \\ & = \frac{(n-1)\ldots(n-k)}{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k)}=\frac{1}{n}.\end{align*}
So $X_{p_i}=\text{Uniform}(\{0,\ldots, n-1\})$. Clearly $X_{p_i}/n\underset{d}{\to}\text{Uniform}(0,1)$.

Great. So, generalinzing this to other distributions $F$ (like the Chi), the solution will be $(1/n) f(i/n)/(1-F(i/n))$. This function (with $t$ instead of $i/n$) is known as the "hazard function", since each time we flip coins, we menace the process to stop. Sadly, I only found closed forms for Uniform (your solution), Exponential (constant) and Weibull. Not for Chi.
